# Does the limit exist when there is a removable discontinuity but the function takes a different value there?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that when there is a hole the limit still exists because the limit is asking what value the function approaches, but does the limit still exist at the hole when the function takes a different value? In the graph on the right is the limit at $x=c$ equal to $L$?[image]

Comment: The limit still exists, it doesn't "care" about the specific value at the exact point. But the function will, obviously, not be continuous.

Comment: Notice that definition of "limit of f(x) as x goes to a is L" is "Given $\epsilon> 0$ there exist $\delta> 0$ such that if $0< |x- a|< \delta$ then $|f(x)- L|< \epsilon$" specifically requires that "$\delta> 0$".  That is, the value of f(a) or even whether f(a) exists is irrelevant to the value of the limit or whether the limit exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the limit still exists **and** it has the same value, so it is still $L$ and *not* $f(c)$.

It's important to understand that the limit of a function $f$ at a point $c$ (its existence *and* its value if it exists) is completely determined by the function values of $f$ *near $c$* but **not** *at $c$*.

Intuitively you could say the limit tries to "predict" $f(c)$ based on the neighboring values of $f$ and it predicts a real number $L$ if the function can be made *continuous* by setting $f(c)=L$.